# How to find why my keys have been rebound?

Tags: key-bindings

Trying to run a new version of emacs, installed on a server that I do not have root privileges on. The tutoral (`C-h t`) reports that keybindings, including `C-v`, have been re-bound.

Is there a way of telling what file caused them to be re-bound, so that I can try to prevent that file from being loaded? `.emacs` is clean so it must be some other file. Many other keybindings have been "helpfully" customised, so it is not realistic to simply reverse these one-by-one.

Comment: Try `emacs -Q`. If the keybindings are unchanged there, then try `emacs -q`.  If they are still unchanged, it's your init file (`~/.emacs` is only one possibility: see [Init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) ). OTOH, if they were changed when you did `-Q` or `-q`, you cannot fix them: complain to your sysadmins.

Comment: You *might* be able to fix changes which occur under `-q`, but it depends on how it was done (`default.el` can be inhibited by your init file, but `site-start.el` cannot).  You can inhibit `site-start.el` by passing `--no-site-file` when you start Emacs, though.  That's implied by `-Q` so if you're still seeing the overrides under *that*, I'd say something unusual is going on.